# Django runs transaction commit too late

Tags: python, django, postgresql

```
def some_view(request):
    with transaction.atomic():
       data = do_some_stuff(request)
       data2 = do_some_stuff2(request)
    async_task.delay(data, data2)
    return Response({'data': data, 'data2': data2})
```

Expectation: when `with` block is completed all database modifications are commited to database.

Reality: while response is being prepared to be sent to browser (serialization) async task already started execution. Async task expects that all modification are already completed, but it is not. Only when browser receives response actual `commit` to database is done.

I know about `transaction.on_commit(func)` hook, but question is about why once `with transaction.atomic()` is completed I can not be sure that data is actually updated in database? Take a note `ATOMIC_REQUESTS=False`

It's about Django 1.11.20 and postgresql 10. I do not know if it works the same way with Django 2+

Comment: transaction.atomic` does not guarantee you time the transaction will be run, it only guarantees that the DB operations inside the `with` block will be atomic.

Comment: Your expectation is correct. That means that there is some other problem here, which unfortunately can't be determined from the minimal pseudocode you posted.